# Create a CSV file with R with content in specified columns

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to create a new table in R from an existing table. 
To illustrate please see the table below:

[image]

The query looks at the 2nd and 3rd column and maps instances that combination occurs to produce a new table.

As you can see, there are no instances of repeat and that is critical. 
I tried doing this using the Unique function but I have not been able to compute it well enough to generate the CSV output to be like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are quite new to R the package sqldf may help you. With this it´s possible to write sql querys in R. If you work with tables this can help.

Your code, for what you want to do would then look like this:

```
install.packages("sqldf")
library(sqldf)
new_table<-sqldf("SELECT Column2, Column3, COUNT(*) as Frequency from old_table group by CONCAT(Column2,Column3)")
write.csv(new_table, "new_table.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate the data, you can put it in a tibble and afterwards use the `dplyr` grammar.

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(col_1=c(14, 5, 7, 688, 56, 565, 674),
       col_2=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C"),
       col_3=c("C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "A", "D"),
       col_4=c("67rhr", "4gg2", "344g5", "4yy4", "6hthht7", "7ttjty7", "yyuuy")) %>% 
    count(col_2, col_3) %>% 
    rename("frequency"=n)

#   col_2 col_3 frequency
#   <chr> <chr>     <int>
# 1     A     A         1
# 2     A     C         2
# 3     B     D         3
# 4     C     D         1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Col1 <- c(12,5,7,688,56,565,674)
ColA <- c("A","A","B","B","B","A","C")
ColB <- c("C", "C","D", "D", "D", "A", "C")
df = data.frame(Col1, ColA, ColB)
library(dplyr)
result <- select(df, ColA, ColB) %>% 
    group_by(ColA, ColB) %>% 
    summarise(Frequency=n())

write.csv(result, file="somename.csv")
```